# Sort by date and skip documents

Tags: mongodb

I'm setting a pagination system in mongoDB, 
I want to get the elements ordered by date when skipping other elements
my code:

```
$hospitals=$qb->select(''title','date','photos','description')
            ->field('coordinates')
            ->near(
                (float)$lat,
                (float)$lng) 
            ->field('active')
            ->equals(1)
               ->sort('date','desc')
            ->skip(9*$page)
            ->limit(9)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
            ->toArray();
```

It alywas give me the same records.
I don't know how I should order the limit , skip and sort..

Comment: What PHP Library are you using to interact with MongoDB?

Comment: Doctrine2 ODM that is.